# Problem after adding <form>?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

When i added `<form>` to my web page, all my javascript stopped working, and when i put the form at the begining of my table submit wont work, what i am doing wrong. below is my code after testing on other browser it works fine but on Firefox it doesn't

Update: After checking on firefox java error console it appears that `Checking` Function is defined

Update2: Solved my mistake was `<script type="text/jscript">` is wrong thats why on firefox it wasn't working and on the rest it was, it must be `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sabay Afrah.Inc | Contact Us</title>
<script src="js/clear.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/SpryValidationSelect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/jscript">

function Checking(form){

if(empty(form.fname.value){

         alert("do nothing");

         }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.address {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="theme/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme/SpryValidationSelect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<form  action="enterdb.php" method="post">
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width="1006" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="93" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="374" ><img src="images/logo.png" width="230" height="114" /></td>
        <td width="426" align="right" class="address">
        10 GlenLake parkway<br />
Suite 130, mailbox # 76<br />
Atlanta, GA 30328<br />
Phone #: + 678-222-3442<br />
Fax #: +678-222-3401<br />
Office hours: M-F 8:30 a.m. to 5:00 p.m.<br />
        </td>
        <td width="99">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="title">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="84"><br /></td>
            <td width="516" class="title">Contact Us</td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

    <table width="883" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="table">
        <td width="27" rowspan="10" bgcolor="#330099" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#330099" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="29" rowspan="8" bgcolor="#330099" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr >
        <td width="139" height="31" bgcolor="#330099" class="textable">First Name:</td> <td>

         <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" size="40" /> </td>
        <td width="150" class="textable">Last Name:</td>
        <td width="265" class="textable"><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td ><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td ><input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" size="40"  /></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td width="32" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="30" class="textable">Subject:</td> <td>
          <span id="spryselect1">
            <label>
              <select name="sub" id="sub">
              <option> Choose a Subject</option>
              <option> General Question</option>
              <option> MemberShip Area</option>
              <option> Others</option>

              </select>
            </label>
            <span class="selectRequiredMsg">Please select a Subject.</span></span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="33" class="textable">Company Name:</td> <td> <input id="cname" name="cname" type="text" size="40"   /></td>
        <td class="textable">Company Address:</td>
        <td class="textable"><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <tr>
           <td><input id="cadd" name="cadd" type="text" size="40" onclick=""  /></td>
          </tr>

        </table></td>

        <td class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" class="textable">Phone Number:</td> <td><input id="phonen" name="phonen" type="text" size="40"  /> </td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="31" class="textable">Fax Number:</td><td> <input id="faxn" name="faxn" type="text" size="40" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="32" class="textable">Email Address:</td><td><input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="40" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="textable">Additional Information:</td>
        <td colspan="5" class="textable"><table width="600" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">

            <textarea id="add" name="add" cols="70" rows="10" /></textarea>
            </td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" class="textable">
              <input name="Submit" type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="Checking()"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center" class="textable">

            <input type="reset"  value="Clear" />



            </td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="textable">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var spryselect1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect1");
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: saying "all my javascript stopped" isn't terrible helpful... perhaps "my form validation stopped" would give us a better indication of your problem.

Comment: hey there, you know why i said that because SpryValidationSelect.js stop working when i insert `form` this script wont allow to bypass without choosing something from the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an onsubmit to your form tag:

```
<form  action="enterdb.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return Checking(this);">
```

Then remove the onclick event from the submit button.

You need to pass a form object to the Checking function, hence the `this`. Also it's usually better to place the handler in the form tag as it'll be called when the user submits the form by either clicking the submit button or by pressing enter elsewhere in the form.

Edited per webdestroya.

Comment: hey there, nope still not checking, it bypass the script and cont on submitting

Comment: it should be `onsubmit="return Checking(this)"`

Comment: i checked the page using IE it worked like a charm but when i check it through FF it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Your function wants to take in the form element and your submit button doesn't send anything to the function. I'd assume it's not submitting because your function is erroring out and thus stopping the button as if it were returning false. Fix your JavaScript, try using Firebug to help you find these problems.

Comment: the way I often address this is to go in with firebug and trace through my onsubmit function

Comment: ya its amazing but it keep on crashing, and nothing it shows no error after running profile

Answer (score 0):

generally, suggest that you comment out first clear.js and SpryValidationSelect.js, and then try run your code by adding one by one javascript file to clearly defined what is the file that been crashing with your inline code text.

also try to add name for your form and try like this:

```
function Checking(form){

  if(empty(window.myform.fname.value){

         alert("do nothing");

         }
  }
```

in a way to debug something, its best to try different method by which sometimes you will spot the not easier.

just my thought. gudluck